# Batch file with custom commands

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that can have multiple commands. For example, if I just execute the batch file, it would function normally, and if I execute that command with an argument, it would take me to a certain part of the batch. Here is the code that I managed to do:

```
@echo off
if not defined %1 goto 2
if %1 equ 1 goto 1

:1
echo 1
pause
exit /b

:2
echo 2

pause
```

But the code has a problem. How can we define %1? When I run the batch file without any arguments, the output is :

```
2
Press any key to continue...
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: i don't understand. if `%1` is blank, it should expand to `if not defined goto 2`, which is intercepted as if a variable called `goto` is not defined, do `2`, which is not you want!

Comment: `if defined` only works for environment variables but not for argument references; to simply work around that just assign the argument to a variable and check it then: `set "ARG1=%~1"`, then `if defined ARG ...`...

Answer (score 1):

As your example is using very simple single digit arguments, and those are unlikely to be used as labels in a real working script, here's a version which should work with any of your labels without having to use `if` comparisons for each in advance:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

If Not "%~1" == "" %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /ILX ":%~1" "%~f0">NUL && GoTo %~1

:NoArg
Echo No valid argument was received & Pause
GoTo :EOF

:UserName
Echo %%UserName%% = %UserName% & Pause
GoTo :EOF

:ComputerName
Echo %%ComputerName%% = %ComputerName% & Pause
GoTo :EOF

:UserDomain
Echo %%UserDomain%% = %UserDomain% & Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Date
Echo %%Date%% = %Date% & Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Time
Echo %%Time%% = %Time% & Pause
GoTo :EOF
```

I've put example code into each label for demonstration purposes, *(you can obviously adjust yours to suit your specific needs)*.

The `FindStr` command is used here to read all lines within the script which begin with a colon `:`, *(i.e. the labels)*, followed by the case insensitive input argument only. If no input argument was received or the match fails, the default first label will be used.

Answer (score 1):

`%1` is only defined when you pass arguments to the file so if you don't pass any arguments it will always make the `if %1 not defined` comparison be true. If you want to be able to define %1 while running the script, this is what I would suggest:

```bat
@echo off
set var=%1
:start
if not defined %var% goto set
if %var% equ "1" goto 1
:set
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
set /p var="What arguments do you want to pass? "
:1
echo 1
pause
exit /b

:2
echo 2

pause
```

Answer (score -1):

When you run that with no arguments, `%1` is nothing so you will get this line:

`if not defined goto 2`

What you want is to make sure you don't end up with anything empty:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" equ "" goto 2
if "%~1" equ "1" goto 1

:1
echo 1
pause
exit /b

:2
echo 2

pause
```

Comment: Btw what is so different from %1 and %~1

Comment: `call /?`  `%~1` will remove any surrounding double quotes.  You don't want double double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. :)